# Wordpress - Nested list of categories & subcategories with post cont

Tags: wordpress, nested

I am new and leaning WordPress. I use sahifa theme. I have some problem. I want to create web site for book there for I want some nested category in main category. I create parent category name “book” and add it in navigation, now I want to show nested category in this page.

Examples are Give Below.

1. Book (Parent Category)
2. Science fiction (child Category)
3. Satire (child Category)
4. Drama (child Category)
5. Romance (child Category)

I want book as a parent category and in which all nested category show with category name, category image if assign and show post count which are in this nested category.
I also want to use custom field for post in which I want to show book author name, online book reading link etc.
Can anyone help me?

Regards

Muhammad Fahim

Answer (score -2):

You can use this plugin: List all posts by Authors, nested Categories and Titles  https://wordpress.org/plugins/list-all-posts-by-authors-nested-categories-and-titles/